# Add class on parent div - React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm really struggling to see how to do this. I want to add a class on click somewhere in one of the parent element which is not available in my code.

I think it would be something like this with jQuery:

```
$('.child').parent('parent').addClass('the-class')
```

I want to know how to use the above code in React.

Comment: Add a useRef to any parent HTML element. Then you can add a click event listener to a child of this useRef.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: useRef is the correct way to do this in react.  To do an exact one for one is not a react thing it's vanilla JS - onClick={(e)=>{e.target.closest('.parent').classList.add('the-class')}} - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback down from the parent that will trigger the parent to change a state value which will then control a class. I will show an example below,

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [extraClass, setExtraClass] = useState(false);
    const invertClass = () => setExtraClass(!extraClass);

    return (
        <div className={extraClass ? 'the-class' : ''}>
            <Child changeClass={invertClass} />
        </div>
    )
}

const Child = (props) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => invertClass}>
            Click me to change the parents class.
        </div>
    )
}
```

Obviously they should be put into separate files, the right imports should be added, and all of your other code should be implemented. This is just the idea of what you are trying to do, and you will be able to fix your code with the above implementation.

Just comment if you need any more help and I would be happy to help you out.

Comment: Thank you for the code @caidensanders but there is no parent div available where I can put className condition. I'm using MS Dynamic Commerce Modal Popup where you cannot edit on view files.

Comment: No worries! Is it possible that you could provide me with your current code? I can then try to find a solution that will fit your specific code.